# Not authorized by proxy , ReasonPhrase:Proxy Authorization Required. in maven build

Tags: proxy

I am building opendaylight code into my ubuntu machine which runs behind my corporate proxy.I have even added SSL certificate in my jdk1.8 but no effect.
I m getting an error after having did proxy settings in settings.xml and my url pointing to nexus central repository.

error after mvn clean install --
Downloading: https://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/public/org/opendaylight/odlparent/odlparent-lite/1.8.1-Carbon/odlparent-lite-1.8.1-Carbon.pom
Aug 23, 2017 12:01:04 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.client.protocol.RequestProxyAuthentication process
WARNING: NEGOTIATE authentication error: Invalid name provided (Mechanism level: KrbException: Cannot locate default realm)
Aug 23, 2017 12:01:04 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.client.protocol.RequestProxyAuthentication process
WARNING: NTLM authentication error: Credentials cannot be used for NTLM authentication: org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project org.opendaylight.controller:releasepom:0.5.1-Carbon (/home/cts/controller-release-carbon-sr1/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not transfer artifact org.opendaylight.odlparent:odlparent-lite:pom:1.8.1-Carbon from/to nexus (https://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/public/): **Not authorized by proxy , ReasonPhrase:Proxy Authorization Required.** and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 4, column 11 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]

settings.xml looks like---

```
<proxies><proxy>
  <id>myproxy</id>
  <active>true</active>
  <protocol>http</protocol>
  <username>my userid</username>  
  <password>mypassword</password>  
  <host>proxy.example.com</host>   
  <port>8080</port>         
</proxy>  
</proxies>
<servers>
    <server>
        <id>nexus</id>
        <username>nexusid</username>
        <password>nexuspassword/password>
    </server>
    <server>
        <id>TomcatServer</id>
        <username>admin</username>
        <password>password</password>
    </server>   
</servers>
<mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <id>nexus</id>
        <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
    <url>https://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/public/</url>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>
```

can anyone plz help to fix this proxy issue?